# Prefilling Flash Login Form with Username and Password

Tags: flash

My problem is rather simple. I have a site built totally in flash that I need a couple other people to be able to log into, but I don't want them to know the password.

Does anyone know if there a way that I can load the flash site in an iframe, and then use some javascript to fill the flash username and password with the correct text so that they can just click the login button without knowing the username and password?

If not, can anyone think of any other ways to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are many ways to accomplish this but using an IFrame is one of them. I don't know your setup so I will be rather broad.

You'll want to use JavaScript to set FlashVars in the HTML or JavaScript where your Flash Object is loading the SWF.

Once you've done this, you can then take the value from those FlashVars and set the textfields' value as the value of the FlashVars.

Comment: Can I actually do all of that without editing the flash file? I don't have access to the flash code. All I have to work with is a .swf file.

Comment: Nope, you'd have to do that in ActionScript. Without the FLA it's impossible.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm out of luck then. Thanks for answering anyways.